# How to write output in TraditionalForm into external text files?

Tags: export, output-formatting, files-and-directories

I'd like to write output in TraditionalForm into external text files `ofile.txt`.  I tried to use

```
s = OpenWrite["/home/tigerhead/log/ofile.txt", FormatType -> TraditionalForm];
$Output = s;
<run various Mathematica programs>
Close[s];
```

but get errors:

```
Intersection::normal: 
   Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in 
    Intersection[{StandardForm, TraditionalForm}, FormatType].
Options::optnf: 
   FormatType is not a known option for 
    Intersection[OutputStream[/home/tigerhead/log/ofile.txt, 21], {OutputStream[/home/tigerhead/log/ofile.txt, 20], OutputStream[stdout, 1], 
      OutputStream[stderr, 2], OutputStream[/home/tigerhead/<<38>>.txt, 
       21], stdout, stderr}].
```

Any one has a clue?

Comment: What do you expect to see when you open the txt file with a text editor?

Comment: And compare with this `Sin[x] Tan[x]/x^2 // TraditionalForm`

Comment: @MaThEmAtika If you need just plain text why not to use `InputForm` or `OutpuForm`? Why do you need `TraditionalForm` - it's just for displaying thing nicely, which is the opposite of plain text. Could you please explain.

Comment: InputForm writes `"` unnecessarily in many places and make the text harder to read.  OutputForm is the thing I just tried while replying @Heike.  Unfortunately, it didn't fix the errors I reported in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full solution, but to get rid of the error you could try setting (note the curly brackets)

```
$Output = {s}
```

or even

```
$Output = Append[$Output, s]
```

if you want the output to be printed to `sdout` as well. Note that this still writes expressions to the file in `OutputFormat` by default even with `FormatType -> TraditionalForm` in `s`.

Comment: +1 for the `Append[]` idea.

Comment: After using `$Output = Append[$Output, s]`, I still get the same errors.  Now the output is not only written to the file but also displayed on screen, which is good but doesn't solve the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, because to see `TraditionalForm` formatting you need Mathematica Front End. .TXT format is hardly suitable for that. Yet we can do something like this:

Consider an expression:

```
TraditionalForm[HoldForm[D[Integrate[f[t, x], x], t]]]
```

[image]

How do you intend to see that in .TXT format? Mathematica will still try though. Create and open a new stream for writing:

```
 s = OpenWrite["testfile.txt"]
```

> OutputStream["testfile.txt", 120]

Write an expression to the stream:

```
Write[s, TraditionalForm[HoldForm[D[Integrate[f[t, x], x], t]]]]
```

Close the stream:

```
 Close[s]
```

> "testfile.txt"

Print the resulting file:

```
FilePrint["testfile.txt"]
```

[image]

See what is really inside it:

```
Import["testfile.txt"]
```

[image]

Comment: The last image shows what I'd like to have in the text file.  I.e. I want a plain text file of output of my M program.

Comment: @MaThEmAtika Does it mean I answered your question? BTW what type of output your program produces? - can it be a graphics object?

Comment: Most are text for indicating the status and progress of my program, some of which can have highlighting using `Pane[]`, `Style[]` etc.  But it occasionally can print some math too.

Comment: "it mean I answered your question?"  Really?  Aer you saying what I was doing is OK?  Why the errors then?

Comment: @MaThEmAtika If you need just plain text why not to use `InputForm` or `OutpuForm`? Why do you need `TraditionalForm` - it's just for displaying thing nicely, which is the opposite of plain text. Could you please explain.

Comment: InputForm puts `"` unnecessarily around strings and make a sentence broken by several `"` and is ugly for my purpose, i.e. report for non-Mathematica-programmers to read.